# How to give divs the same height when their content is dynamic

Tags: html, css

Basically, I'm looking for a way to make a set of 4 divs have the same height. The content of the divs is dynamic so sometimes extended content will force one of the divs to expand vertically and making the height of each div in the set inconsistent. It's best explained by this example:

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="answers">
  <div class="a-b">
    <a href="#" class="answer" id="A">Michael Jackson</a>
        <a href="#" class="answer" id="B">Stevie Wonder</a>
    </div>
    <div class="c-d">
        <a href="#" class="answer" id="C">Lionel Richie</a>
        <a href="#" class="answer" id="D">This answer could contain more text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.answers {
    margin-top: 35px;
}
.a-b {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.c-d {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}
.answer {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #1797FF;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 33px;
    font-size: 22px;
    width: 75%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

How could I keep that 2x2 layout and force each div to be the same height (dictated by the div with the largest amount of text)?

[JSfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/h53ag4p7/)

Answer (score 1):

Flex box has a lot of cool features, but for now I prefer a jquery solution because is more compatible with old browsers.

This plugin can help You:
http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

you can set the same height for all elements or for single row.

this is the basic usage:

```
$(function() {
    $('.answer').matchHeight(options);
});
```

Comment: Perhaps, a Flexible Box polyfill is the best of both worlds? See https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#flexible-box-layout-spec . I have not tried any of these, so can't say anything about how well they work.

Comment: If there Modernizr installed for other polyfills, use a css solution with fallback can be clean.
In my opinion also a javascript solution only is acceptable, especially if Modernizr is not used in the project for other issues.

Answer (score 1):

After spending way too much time on this I gave up with CSS and used a jQuery solution:

```
var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $(".answer").map(function() {
    return $(this).height();
}).get());

$(".answer").attr('style', 'height: ' + maxHeight + 'px');
```

Comment: In terms of getting the job done concisely, I like this answer. Here is the fiddle for convenience. https://jsfiddle.net/h53ag4p7/26/

Comment: I prefer use matcheight.js plugin because already manages responsive issues when the window is resized.

Comment: @docta_faustus did you see my answer? using CSS only

Answer (score 0):

You can use `line clamp`

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.answers {
  margin-top: 35px;
  font-size: 0;
}
.answer {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 48%;
  border-radius: 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #1797FF;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 33px;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 0 1% 20px;
  min-height: 70px;
}
.answer span {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.using-overflow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 48%;
  border-radius: 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #1797FF;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 33px;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 0 1% 20px;
}

.using-overflow span {
  display: block;
  line-height: 24px;
  height: 48px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="answers">
  <a href="#" class="answer"><span>Michael Jackson Michael Jackson Michael Jackson Michael Jackson </span></a>
  <a href="#" class="answer"><span>Stevie Wonder</span></a>
  <a href="#" class="answer"><span>Lionel Richie</span></a>
  <a href="#" class="answer"><span>This answer could contain more text This answer could contain more text</span></a>
</div>

<h1>using overflow</h1>
<div class="answers">
  <a href="#" class="using-overflow"><span>Michael Jackson Michael Jackson Michael Jackson Michael Jackson</span></a>
  <a href="#" class="using-overflow"><span>Stevie Wonder</span></a>
  <a href="#" class="using-overflow"><span>Lionel Richie</span></a>
  <a href="#" class="using-overflow"><span>This answer could contain more text This answer could contain more text</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work well in Chrome but sadly it has poor cross-browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=line-clamp

Comment: yup, but it is the best idea, and if you're looking for any other option, use `height` + `line-height` + `overflow`

Comment: Thanks but that second option is specifying a static height. Sometimes the answers could all be one line so they would all need to "shrink." Also, I wouldn't want to use `overflow: hidden` since that could cut off longer answers.

Comment: min-height: 70px isn't letting the answer divs shrink below 2 lines worth of text.

Answer (score -1):

This is a long-standing problem:

There are only two ways that work consistently...

- Use the latest flexbox CSS on your divs (display:flex - you will need to look up the specifications) but it is the ultimate answer!
- If you need to support IE less than 11, then sadly the only simple available option is to use presentational tables (this works, but is not recommended) - otherwise you are forced to use javascript to adjust the height of divs after initial load.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.